# Datacontext Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml

It's the first time I'm creating a windows 8 app, simply because I have to for school project. I'm not new to databinding etc in xaml but is it different when creating a W8 app because it's not working like I normally do.

XAML code: (my datatemplate is in )

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource test}" DataContext="{Binding ListLineup}">
<DataTemplate x:Key="test">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Model: (data loaded from JSON file)

```
public class LineUp
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Until { get; set; }

    public LineUp(string id, string date, string from, string until)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Date = date;
        this.From = from;
        this.Until = until;
    }

    public static async Task<List<LineUp>> GetLineUp()
    {
        List<LineUp> lineup = new List<LineUp>();
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string url = @"http://localhost:28603/api/LineUp";
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    content = "{'lineups':" + content + "}";

                    ListLineUp CollectionOfLineUps = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<ListLineUp>(content);
                    foreach (LineUp newLineup in CollectionOfLineUps.lineups)
                    {
                        lineup.Add(newLineup);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception when getting the LineUps. API is down ");
                }
            }
        }
        return lineup;
    }
}

public class ListLineUp
{
    public List<LineUp> lineups { get; set; } 
}
```

Code behind XAML:

```
 public async void GetAllNeededLists()
    {
        ListLineup = await LineUp.GetLineUp();
        foreach (var lu in ListLineup)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(lu.Date);
        }

    }
```

When running I get all the data in Debug window with my dates. 
There is a textblock when I run the app, but there is no content in it.

Comment: I have not had luck doing it the way you have done; I have always had to do `Control.ItemsSource = myEnumerable;` (Or in some cases .DataContext)

Answer (score 0):

To show items in ItemsControl you need to set ItemsSource property with IEnumerable object.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding lineups}"/>
```

And set your ListLineUp object into `DataContext` above ListView.

To set DataTemplate, use `ItemTemplate` property.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>...</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did use itemsSource before datacontext but that didn't work either. My datatemplate is in my <page.resources>

Comment: `DataContext` property defines in which object system will look for desired property. Also if you don't set `DataContext`, it will take `DataContext` from parent element. Also look into Debug Output in Visual Studio, all binding errors are logged there.

Comment: I have no errors in my debug. This is my datacontext now 
DataContext="{Binding ListLineup, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
and Itemssource is lineups, although I don't get why I have to put lineups as itemssource? Still not working unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ItemsSource` and not the DataContext of the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource test}" ItemsSource="{Binding ListLineup}">
```